# Maven modules project copying module JARs in Maven (using IntelliJ)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module, pom.xml

We have a project in intellij that is maven based with some submodules.  The problem here is how to copy the JAR files to the root parent-project `target` folder when running the package goal.

## Setup

`acme.calculator.client` is the main project and has a dependency on `acme.calculator`.  Each of those modules has a POM file.  The `parent-project` also has a POM file.

The maven project has the following structure:

```
parent-project
├── acme.calculator
│   └── pom.xml
├── acme.calculator.client
│   └── pom.xml
└── pom.xml
```

### acme.calculator pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>acme.parent</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>acme.calculator</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

### acme.calculator.client pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>acme.parent</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>acme.calculator.client</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>acme.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>acme.calculator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- this will build an executable jar file by creating the manifest.mf -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>acme.calculator.client.Program</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### root pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>acme.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>acme.calculator</module>
        <module>acme.calculator.client</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-artifact</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## Executing

To execute this in IntelliJ we are running the `package` goal on the `parent-project`:

[image: run package goal]

## Issues

The JAR files are built for each module into their own respective `target` folder for acme.calculator and acme.calculator.client.  Which is good.

### acme.calculator.client output

```
acme.calculator.client
└──target
     ├── acme.calculator.client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
     └── libs    
         └── acme.calculator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

### parent-project output

```
parent-project
└──target
     └── parent-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

We've been going round in circles this morning looking at different articles but this is the first time we have used `Maven`.

Comment: Why would you like to copy the jars into the root parent `target` folder? What is the intention of copying?

Comment: It sounds like you need some detailed training about Maven... would make things easier and would safe time...

Comment: We are just learning maven and was assuming it was the thing to do - collate all artifacts? 

If it isn't then great.  Ultimately the build is in `jenkins` also where the artifacts will be downloaded from.

Comment: As I asked: Why would you like to copy the jars into the root parent? What is the intention of that? Would you like to create an executable jar? Would you like to create an archive of it? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: So at the minute `acme.calculator.client` is the executable jar.  The purpose of a root would be just to have a single place to get the jars from `jenkins` - I guess a single archive as you put it.

Although the next step on this journey is looking at publishing to a maven repo (nexus) where the modules would be pulled from and consumed in other projects.